# How can I make this slider loop automatically with a certain delay? ie. 1000ms

Tags: javascript, html, loops, web, slider

can anyone explain how to make [this](https://codepen.io/nathantaylor/pen/JEXgpj) slider loop automatically as well?

Here is only the javascript for simplicity:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i=1; i <= $('.slider__slide').length; i++){
    $('.slider__indicators').append('<div class="slider__indicator" data-slide="'+i+'"></div>')
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider__wrap').addClass('slider__wrap--hacked');
  }, 1000);
})

function goToSlide(number){
  $('.slider__slide').removeClass('slider__slide--active');
  $('.slider__slide[data-slide='+number+']').addClass('slider__slide--active');
}

$('.slider__next, .go-to-next').on('click', function(){
  var currentSlide = Number($('.slider__slide--active').data('slide'));
  var totalSlides = $('.slider__slide').length;
  currentSlide++
  if (currentSlide > totalSlides){
    currentSlide = 1;
  }
  goToSlide(currentSlide);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your sliding function out into it's own function, use setInterval instead of setTimeout to loop the transition, and then move that sliding function into that setInterval. Here is the JS:

```js
var loopInterval;

$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i=1; i <= $('.slider__slide').length; i++){
    $('.slider__indicators').append('<div class="slider__indicator" data-slide="'+i+'"></div>')
  }
  loopInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $('.slider__wrap').addClass('slider__wrap--hacked');
    slidingFunction();
  }, 10 * 1000);
})

function goToSlide(number){
  $('.slider__slide').removeClass('slider__slide--active');
  $('.slider__slide[data-slide='+number+']').addClass('slider__slide--active');
}

$('.slider__next, .go-to-next').on('click', nextClick)

function slidingFunction() {
  var currentSlide = Number($('.slider__slide--active').data('slide'));
  var totalSlides = $('.slider__slide').length;
  currentSlide++
  if (currentSlide > totalSlides){
    currentSlide = 1;
  }
  goToSlide(currentSlide);
}

function nextClick(){
  clearInterval(loopInterval);
  loopInterval = setInterval(slidingFunction, 10 * 1000);
  slidingFunction();
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/nick-siegmundt/pen/MWwQgVr

Comment: Thanks, it works great. is there also a way to reset the timer when I manually click the next slide? because now when I click it jumps 2 slides because of the timer finishing and my click.

Comment: @SamZ yeah you'll just have to create a separate function and use `clearInterval`. Check my codepen again for updated code

Comment: Thanks! Also, the images became gray in between transitions with your code, why is that?

Comment: Oops, i accidentally deleted a part of your code that was changing some class. Try it now

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: can you please help me with this one as well, it would be very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694967/how-can-i-add-the-ken-burns-effect-to-this-slider