# How can I add the ken burns effect to this slider?

Tags: html, css, web, slider, css-animations

can anyone explain how to add the Ken Burns effect to [this](https://codepen.io/nick-siegmundt/pen/MWwQgVr) slider?

I tried adding the following to the keyframes but it didn't work:

```
95% {
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-190px, -120px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    transform: scale3d(2, 2, 2) translate3d(-170px, -100px, 0px);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

what is the explanation that it doesn't work on this case?

Here is the original CSS code only for simplicity:

```
$main: #777;
$back: #aaa;
$accent: hsl(220,50%,40%);

$sans: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$heebo: 'Heebo', sans-serif;

$base: 3vh;

$time: 1800ms;

$ease-out: cubic-bezier(0.260, 0.005, 0.135, 1.000);
$ease-in-out: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.150, 0.860);

body{
  background: $back;
  font-family: $sans
}

.slider{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: $main;
  overflow: hidden;;

  &__wrap{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform $time/4 $ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transition-delay: $time/4;
    opacity: 0;
    &--hacked{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  &__back{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size:  auto 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: none;
    transition: filter $time/4 $ease-in-out;
  }

  &__inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0%;
    background-size: auto 133.3333%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: none;
    transform: scale(0.75);
    transition: transform $time/4 $ease-in-out, box-shadow $time/4 $ease-in-out, opacity $time/4 step-end;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 $base $base rgba(darken($accent,50%),0);
    padding: $base*5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  &__content{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: white;
    font-family: $heebo;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity $time/4;
    h1{
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: $base*3;
      line-height: 0.85;
      margin-bottom: $base/4;
      pointer-events: none;
      text-shadow: 0 $base/8 $base/4 rgba(darken($accent,50%),0.1);
    }
    a{
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: $base*0.8;
      letter-spacing: $base*0.1;
      font-weight: 100;
      position: relative;
      &:after{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: $base*3;
        background: white;
        height: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: $base*2;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform-origin: 0% 50%;
        transition: transform $time/2 $ease-in-out;
      }
      &:before{
        content: '';
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
        display: block;
        width: $base/3;
        height: $base/3;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
        position: absolute;
        font-family: $heebo;
        font-weight: 100;
        top: 50%;
        left: $base*5;
        transition: transform $time/2 $ease-in-out;
      }
      &:hover{
        &:after{
          transform: scaleX(1.5);
          transition: transform $time*2/3 $ease-in-out;
        }
        &:before{
          transform: translateX(#{$base*2}) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
          transition: transform $time*2/3 $ease-in-out;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &__slide{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    //transform: translatex(-100%);
    transition: transform $time/3 $ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: $time/3;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 0;

    &--active{
      transform: translatex(0%);
      z-index: 2;
      .slider__wrap{
        transform: translateX(0);
        transform-origin: 100% 50%;
        opacity: 1;
        animation: none;
      }
      .slider__back{
        filter: blur(#{$base*0.5});
        transition: filter $time/2 $ease-in-out;
        transition-delay: $time/2 !important;
      }
      .slider__inner{
        transform: scale(0.80);
        box-shadow: 0 $base/3 $base*2 rgba(darken($accent,50%),0.2);
        pointer-events: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: transform $time/2 $ease-in-out, box-shadow $time/2 $ease-in-out, opacity 1ms step-end;
        transition-delay: $time/2;
      }
      .slider__content{
        opacity: 1;
        transition-delay: $time*3/4;
      }
    }

    &:not(.slider__slide--active) .slider__wrap{
      @keyframes hack{
        0%{
          transform: translateX(0);
          opacity: 1;
        }
        50%{
          transform: translateX(-100vw);
          opacity: 1;
        }
        51%{
          transform: translateX(-100vw);
          opacity: 0;
        }
        52%{
          transform: translateX(100vw);
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100%{
          transform: translateX(100vw);
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
      animation-name: hack;
      animation-duration: $time/2;
      animation-delay: $time/4;
      animation-timing-function: $ease-in-out;
    }

    &:nth-child(1) .slider__back, &:nth-child(1) .slider__inner{
      background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=931);
      //background: #eee;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) .slider__back, &:nth-child(2) .slider__inner{
      background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=929);
      //background: #aaa;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) .slider__back, &:nth-child(3) .slider__inner{
      background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=927);
      //background: #888;
    }
  }


}


.sig{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

I'm still a beginner, so please try to explain in detail if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below scss :

```
$main: #777;
$back: #aaa;
$accent: hsl(220,50%,40%);

$sans: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$heebo: 'Heebo', sans-serif;

$base: 3vh;

$time: 1800ms;
$time_back: 20s;

$ease-out: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
$ease-in-out: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

body{
  background: $back;
  font-family: $sans
}

.slider{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: $main;
  overflow: hidden;;

  &__wrap{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(100vw);
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform $time/4 $ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transition-delay: $time/4;
    opacity: 0;
    &--hacked{
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  &__back{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size:  auto 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: none;
    transition: filter $time/4 $ease-in-out;
  }

  &__inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0%;
    background-size: auto 133.3333%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: none;
    transform: scale(0.75);
    transition: transform $time/4 $ease-in-out, box-shadow $time/4 $ease-in-out, opacity $time/4 step-end;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 $base $base rgba(darken($accent,50%),0);
    padding: $base*5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  &__content{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: white;
    font-family: $heebo;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity $time/4;
    h1{
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: $base*3;
      line-height: 0.85;
      margin-bottom: $base/4;
      pointer-events: none;
      text-shadow: 0 $base/8 $base/4 rgba(darken($accent,50%),0.1);
    }
    a{
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: $base*0.8;
      letter-spacing: $base*0.1;
      font-weight: 100;
      position: relative;
      &:after{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: $base*3;
        background: white;
        height: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: $base*2;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform-origin: 0% 50%;
        transition: transform $time/2 $ease-in-out;
      }
      &:before{
        content: '';
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
        display: block;
        width: $base/3;
        height: $base/3;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
        position: absolute;
        font-family: $heebo;
        font-weight: 100;
        top: 50%;
        left: $base*5;
        transition: transform $time/2 $ease-in-out;
      }
      &:hover{
        &:after{
          transform: scaleX(1.5);
          transition: transform $time*2/3 $ease-in-out;
        }
        &:before{
          transform: translateX(#{$base*2}) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
          transition: transform $time*2/3 $ease-in-out;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &__slide{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    //transform: translatex(-100%);
    transition: transform $time/3 $ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: $time/3;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 0;

    &--active{
      transform: translatex(0%);
      z-index: 2;
      .slider__wrap{
        transform: translateX(0);
        transform-origin: 100% 50%;
        opacity: 1;
        animation: none;
      }
      .slider__back{
        filter: blur(#{$base*0.5});
        transition: filter $time/2 $ease-in-out;
        transition-delay: $time/2 !important;
      }
      .slider__inner{
        transform: scale(0.80);
        box-shadow: 0 $base/3 $base*2 rgba(darken($accent,50%),0.2);
        pointer-events: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: transform $time_back/2 $ease-in-out, box-shadow $time_back/2 $ease-in-out, opacity 1ms step-end;
        transition-delay: $time/2;
      }
      .slider__content{
        opacity: 1;
        transition-delay: $time*3/4;
      }
    }

    &:not(.slider__slide--active) .slider__wrap{
      @keyframes hack{
        0%{
          transform: translateX(0);
          opacity: 1;
        }
        50%{
          transform: translateX(-100vw);
          opacity: 1;
        }
        51%{
          transform: translateX(-100vw);
          opacity: 0;
        }
        52%{
          transform: translateX(100vw);
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100%{
          transform: translateX(100vw);
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
      animation-name: hack;
      animation-duration: $time/2;
      animation-delay: $time/4;
      animation-timing-function: $ease-in-out;
    }

    &:nth-child(1) .slider__back, &:nth-child(1) .slider__inner{
      background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=931);
      //background: #eee;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) .slider__back, &:nth-child(2) .slider__inner{
      background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=929);
      //background: #aaa;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) .slider__back, &:nth-child(3) .slider__inner{
      background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/800/?image=927);
      //background: #888;
    }
  }


}


.sig{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the time for inner slider named as $time_back to 20s and updated transition property for inner slider which will take 10 sec for transition effect to complete.